# vb.net Get first day of year/ last day of last month / first day of last month from textbox date

Tags: vb.net, date

I have a simple textbox that I will enter a random date (8/6/2017).  I have three labels.  All I want is label1.text = 1/1/2017 and label2.text = 7/1/2017 and label3.text = 7/31/2017.

It's got to pull these dates based on the date I enter in my textbox and it's not restricted to current year.

Dim 1stDayYr As New Date(Date."" & Textbox.text & "".Year, 1, 1)

Label1.text = 1stDayYr

TBH - I don't even know how to begin getting first day of previous month based on TB date or the last day of previous month based on TB date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim baseDate As DateTime

    Dim beginningOfYear As DateTime
    Dim beginningOfPreviousMonth As DateTime
    Dim endOfPreviousMonth As DateTime

    If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, baseDate) Then
        beginningOfYear = New DateTime(Year(baseDate), 1, 1)

        Dim previous As DateTime = baseDate.AddMonths(-1)
        beginningOfPreviousMonth = baseDate.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1 * previous.Day).AddDays(1)

        endOfPreviousMonth = beginningOfPreviousMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

        Console.WriteLine("Base date: {0} Beginning of year: {1} Beginning of previous month: {2} End of previous month: {3}", baseDate, beginningOfYear, beginningOfPreviousMonth, endOfPreviousMonth)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid date")
    End If
```

But you should use DateTimePicker for date inputs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering and I'm close.

```
Dim previous As DateTime = baseDate.AddMonths(-1)
beginningOfPreviousMonth = baseDate.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1 * previous.Day).AddDays(1)
```

VS didn't like your previous.Day and I don't know why.